# What is the best way to take two near identical sheets and make them identical

Tags: excel, vba

I have two rather large excel sheets that are near identical and I'm trying to take turn the Static Data version into a copy of MAIN. I also check for changes in MAIN to be written to this Static Data sheet every second:

```
Sub macro_timer()
'Tells Excel when to next run the macro.
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CopyMain"

End Sub

Public Sub CopyMain()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Worksheets("Static Data").Cells.ClearContents
    With Worksheets("Static Data")
        
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy .Range("A1")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    End With
    Call macro_timer
End Sub
```

This works on a small table but it seems to crash after a while. Is there a way that I don't need to call `ClearContents` and only write the changes to the Static Data sheet.

Comment: If you only care about making the static sheet equal to the main sheet and not vice versa, surely the best way to do that is to just make a copy and delete the old static sheet.

Comment: Would that work on a 1 second interval?

Comment: Debatable but doing anything every second in VBA is a questionable choice tbh.

Comment: I'm used to python so naturally add-ins/ libraries pop up in my thoughts. Has there got some kind of speed up for the type of code above or deletion.

Comment: You don't need the `.Copy` if you only care about the values in that range